# Code sharing between angular website and angular pwa

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I want to do code sharing between angular website and PWA which will be built using angular itself. How do I do that?

Comment: The PWA is your website (the same code) - you do not need to build two different things. Or are you asking how to share code between two different websites?

Comment: Angular PWA and website are the same thing. It's "Prograssive Web Application (Site)"

Comment: A PWA is more of a off-line first app and I will be using indexed db and cache storage to optimise it.
I can create a single PWA and use it across mobile devices and desktop.
But the service worker is not fully supported in IE and edge so my website will not be accessible in desktop(Checked some popular pwa’s and they don’t work in IE and edge) .
Also, a desktop website might have good UI and different features which will not be responsive when accessing on mobile browsers.
So I am thinking of having a different codebase for website and PWA and keeping shared components in a common module.

Comment: A responsive website that has PWA functionality added to it will then ALSO work wonderfully as a responsive PWA. If you want to build and maintain two codebases that do most things the same, that will be extra work. You are the architect and get to decide how much time you have to build and maintain something.